# Working with bitwise operations to optimize Java Math

Tags: java

In my Java class, I have to calculate the value of Pi accurate to 15 decimal places using the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula. In the formula, I need to calculate the 16 to the power of n (integer from 1 to 50 000 000);

There is the formula I am working with

[image: The Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula]

And here is my code to calculate that:

```
double value = 0.0;

//Calculates and increments value by using the BBP formula
for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        value += (1 / 1) * (
                 (4.0 / ((8 * i) + 1)) - 
                 (2.0 / ((8 * i) + 4)) - 
                 (1.0 / ((8 * i) + 5)) - 
                 (1.0 / ((8 * i) + 6)) );
    } else {
        value += (1.0 / (2L<<(i<<2L))) * (
                 (4.0 / ((8 * i) + 1)) - 
                 (2.0 / ((8 * i) + 4)) - 
                 (1.0 / ((8 * i) + 5)) - 
                 (1.0 / ((8 * i) + 6)) );
    }
}
```

The problem is, I am using a bitwise operation (shift left <<) to optimize the code, as we are given bonus marks if we make the program as fast as possible. And for some reason, no matter what I try, the resulting number calculated from Pi is simply too large to work with. I am able to get the numbers 1 to 1.5324955e+54. After that, the numbers overflow and I get 1 or 0. I am trying to get 3.14159 etc but I get 3.1382357295632852 because of this data overflow.

Can anyone help me with this? Or is it simply not worth using bitwise operations to calculate power?

Comment: You don't need to calculate the power from scratch each time. Each successive term is multiplied by a coefficient that's 1/16 of the size of the the previous one.

Comment: There is no guarantee that bit shift operations will make your program any faster. Until you actually get this to work, I'd recommend sticking with plain math and trusting the (JIT) compiler

Comment: Most modern CPUs can multiply just as fast as they can shift.

Comment: From what I can see, the only way you can really make it faster is by parallelizing each iteration. As @ControlAltDel said you can't guarantee that it will be faster by using different maths operations.

Comment: Not sure if it's optimized away or not, but removing `(1 / 1)` altogether wouldn't hurt. Actually just calculating the value at `0` and starting `i` at `1` would allow you to remove the if statement. Basically `int value = 4 - 1/2 - 1/5 - 1/6; for(int i = 1; i < iterations; ++i) { ... }`.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to recalculate `8 * i` every time either, once per iteration should be enough. And while it might not make your code faster, it'll certainly make it more readable.

Comment: You are constantly recalculating `8 * i`. calculate that once at the start of the loop. Also, why 1 / 1. that's just one. you can completely omit the `(1 / 1) *` part. I doubt the shifting of bits will really optimise it. Got data to back up that claim? And does your professor measure hot runs or cold runs by the jvm?

Comment: Shifting the bits is quite a bit faster than using Math.pow() or Math.exp(Math.log(16) * i) as well for that matter. I ran a test to iterate Math.pow 50M times in a thread and did a start-end time test. I did the same with 1<<(i<<2). The bit shift took 0.83 seconds while the math.pow(16, i) took 20 seconds. The Math.exp(Math.log(16) * i) took 14 seconds. The bit shifting seems quite a bit more efficient. Or maybe I tested it in the wrong environment.

Comment: @ElectricFountainCo It is clear that Math.pow() is much slower, it calculates log and exp using series similar to the one you used for calculating pi.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest value that is expressable as a greater-than-zero double is 2<sup>-2048</sup>.  That formula is going to hit zero as a double for every term above (2048/4), which is 512. Going up to 50,000,000 is 49,999,488 too far.

Comment: So what do you suggest then? I tried calculating Power using Math.exp(Math.log(16) * i), but the calculation time is still too long.

Comment: Either, set `iterations` to not more than about 520, or just set the additional term to zero if `i > 520`

Answer (score 1):

You only need 15 digits? Here you go:

```
class Class {
  private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 15;


  public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println(generatePi());
  }

  private static double generatePi() {
    double pi = 0;
    long sixteenPowK = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < ITERATION_COUNT; k++) {
      pi += 1.0 / sixteenPowK * kthTerm(k);
      sixteenPowK *= 16;
    }
    return pi;
  }

  private static double kthTerm(final int k) {
    return 4.0 / (8.0 * k + 1) 
      - 2.0 / (8.0 * k + 4) 
      - 1.0 / (8.0 * k + 5) 
      - 1.0 / (8.0 * k + 6);
  }
}
```

I'd be curious to see a micro benchmark

Comment: 15 iterations might not give you 15 digits (although since each term is less than 1/16 of the previous one, I guess it must).  You could break out of the loop as soon as `(kthTerm(k) == 0.0)`

Comment: All of these methods work perfectly with extremely fast compile time. But, I need to 50M iterations for my assignment. However I have definitely rethought my approach to my calculation thanks to you guys :)

Comment: @AndrewMcGuinness, I agree that there is no guarantee that n iterations will provide n base10 digits of accuracy. But in the specific case of 15 digits, 15 iterations is enough.

Comment: @ElectricFountainCo, 50M iterations is lots of overkill for 15 digits. However, if you want to calculate pi to a million digits, feel free. Take a look at `java.math.BigDecimal`, it will help you with the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Andreas That's the point of this assignment. We are given a task and we had to optimize it as best as we could. Some of the students in my class managed to compute Pi 50M times in under 0.2 seconds.

Comment: @ElectricFountainCo do you need to compute Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe to k=50M, or do you need to compute pi to 15 digits 50M times? There is a big difference there.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I'm far from being an expert in numerical methods.

In general, to solve any problem, I avoid preoptimizations. Once I find the solution, I start to optimize, only if it is somehow required.

In this case, I've inlined the `8 * i` multiplication to a `factor8` variable, I've removed the `if` inside the loop and have calculated the initial value for `i = 0`, and most important, I have accumulated the value of `(1 / 16) ^ i` in a multiplication.

With these changes, I've managed to calculate the value of PI accurate to 15 decimal places in only `11` iterations. Here's the code:

```
public class Pi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int iterations = 11;
        int start = 1;

        double value = 4.0 - 2.0 / 4.0 - 1.0 / 5.0 - 1.0 / 6.0;

        double oneSixteenth = 1.0 / 16.0;
        double oneSixteenthToN = oneSixteenth;

        for (int i = start; i < iterations; i++) {
            double factor8 = 8.0 * i;
            value += oneSixteenthToN * (
                    (4.0 / (factor8 + 1)) -
                            (2.0 / (factor8 + 4)) -
                            (1.0 / (factor8 + 5)) -
                            (1.0 / (factor8 + 6)));
            oneSixteenthToN *= oneSixteenth;
        }

        System.out.println("value = " + value); // our calculated value

        System.out.println("   pi = " + Math.PI); // exact value
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
value = 3.141592653589793
   pi = 3.141592653589793
```

I must admit that I'm unaware of the cause of the cumulative error in your code, but I'm almost sure that it has to do with the calculation of the `(1 / 16) ^ i` term.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own question. It turns out I did not need bitwise operations at all. Since the program creates 50M iterations to calculate Pi, I can increment a predefined variable by using += and *= operations. Here is my final code, it computes Pi in 50M iterations in under 0.2 seconds.

```
//Computes Pi by using the BBP formula
public double computePi(int iterations) //<=50 000 000
{
    final double d = 1 / 16.0;
    double a = 16.0;
    double b = -8;

    double pi = 0.0;

    for(int k = 0; k < iterations; k++)
    {
        a *= d;
        b += 8;
        pi += a * (4.0 / (b + 1)
                - 2.0 / (b + 4)
                - 1.0 / (b + 5)
                - 1.0 / (b + 6));

    }

    return pi;
}
```

Thank you for all of your input, it has helped me a lot and made me rethink my approach to this problem.